# How to get the atrribute by name in xml files with javascripts?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have set of class and in every class it's filed ... each  filed in tag (TemplateField  name=””)  and it's type in tag (TemplateFieldType  pureName="") like this :

```
-<class>
      -<TemplateDef  title="false" alias="Employee">
          -<fields relType="0">
               -<TemplateField  name=”perso”  inherited="false" description="" >
                      -<fieldType   number="2">
                           <TemplateFieldType  pureName="String" dis="" />
                     </fieldType>
                </TemplateField>
          </fields>
-</class>
```

I need when I read this file to get for each class it's fildes and for every fileds it's type like this :

Employee

String perso

I have a lot of class and a lot of own fileds ... But I here put an example ... I knew I can get the name of class by code :

```
function myFunction(xml) {
    var x, i, xmlDoc, txt;
    xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    txt = "";
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('TemplateDef');
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
        txt += x[i].getAttribute('alias') + "<br>";
    }
```

in my code I get the name of my class ... But How I can to get it's fileds ... 
 I did not knew How to get the fileds and it's type from the xml file above ?

there are any method to get them by name of class (for example "perso") any help?